# how to import a text file into my Eclipse C app (running on embedded processor)

Tags: eclipse

How can I import a text file to my C running on Eclipse debugger?

I want to run a benchmark in C on an Ambiq embedded chip.
Benchmark must first input text data.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse > Run menu > Debug Configurations > Common tab > select and enter Input File path & name.

All stdin (ie. fread, etc.) will now input from the file instead of Console window.